# How to set SplitMasterWorker value as false in giraph

Tags: giraph

I try to execute the giraph custom code from eclipse IDE, and when i try to run the code its showing Exception in thread “main” java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: checkLocalJobRunnerConfiguration: When using LocalJobRunner, must have only one worker since only 1 task at a time!
So i want to set the giraph.SplitMasterWorker=false.How to set it and where to set it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

pass -ca giraph.SplitMasterWorker=false to your application as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running giraph on a single node cluster, then paste "-ca giraph.SplitMasterWorker=false" would help. However, if you try to run giraph on multi-nodes cluster such as AWS EC2 base on hadoop version 2.x.x, then I definitely recommend to modify the mapred-site.xml file adding parameter such mapred.job.tracker value in it.

Answer (score 0):

`giraph.SplitMasterWorker=false` is the variable you have to set while calling the giraph runner. This can be passed in as a custom variable under `-ca`. Also I think you are using `-w` parameter, if you running on your local machine it should not be more than 1 since there are no slave nodes to work as a worker

E.g. `hadoop jar /usr/local/giraph1.0/giraph-examples/target/giraph-examples-1.1.0-for-hadoop-2.7.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar org.apache.giraph.GiraphRunner org.apache.giraph.examples.ConnectedComponentsComputation -vif org.apache.giraph.io.formats.IntIntNullTextInputFormat -vip -vof org.apache.giraph.io.formats.IdWithValueTextOutputFormat -op -w 5 -ca giraph.SplitMasterWorker=false`